# power shell is giving file not found error when renaming a folder

Tags: powershell

What I am trying to do is change the name of a folder if any file in it contains contains string "ErrorCode :value" where the value can be anything other than zero. I have old path in $dirName folder and new path with a suffix Error in $newPath folder.

Here is the code for that

```
$fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path $scriptPath -Recurse -Include *.data
foreach ($file in $fileNames) {
    If (Get-Content $file | %{$_ -match '"ErrorCode": 0'}) 
{

}
else{
    $dirName= Split-Path $file
    $newPath=$dirName+"Error"
    Rename-Item $dirName $newPath
}
}
```

I expect it to rename the folder instead it gives me an error that it does not exist.

How do I solve that? Also is there any better approach for this situation because I have started learning powershell before two days?

Comment: For debugging purposes, add `-WhatIf` switch to `Rename-Item` to see if your paths are correct. Also, `Test-Path` can be used to check if a path already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are multiple `*.data`-files in the same folder you code will rename the folder after it found the first file that does NOT contain `"ErrorCode": 0`. When it tries to get the next file or to rename the folder again, it won't be able to find it since it has been renamed.

You wrote you want to rename the folder  `if` the file `-match '"ErrorCode": 0'` but if this condition is fulfilled you execute `{}` (nothing). However if the condition is not fulfilled you execute your code `else{...}`

To prevent your code from renaming the folder multiple times while working in the folder, collect the foldernames first in an array an rename them later:

```
$fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path $scriptPath -Recurse -Include *.data
$FoldersToRename = @() #initialize as array

foreach ($file in $fileNames) {
    If (Get-Content $file | %{$_ -match '"ErrorCode": 0'}) 
    {
        $FoldersToRename += Split-Path $file
    }
}

$SingelFolders = $FoldersToRename | Select-Object -Unique #Select every folder just once
$SingelFolders | ForEach-Object { 
    $newPath=$_ + "Error"
    Rename-Item $_ $newPath
}
```

---

**edit**: Matching anything BUT `'"ErrorCode": 0'`

`-match` uses regular expressions (regex) wich comes very handy in here.
Any single-digit number but `0` would be `[1-9]` in regex. If your ErrorCode can have multiple digits, you can use `\d{2,}` to match 2 or more (`{2,}`) numbers (`\d`). Combined these would look like this: `([1-9]|\d{2,})` (`|` = or)
And here is it in the code from above:

```
foreach ($file in $fileNames) {
    If (Get-Content $file | %{$_ -match '"ErrorCode": ([1-9]|\d{2,})'}) 
    {
        $FoldersToRename += Split-Path $file
    }
}
```

**edit2**: Ignoring whitespaces /tabs:

regex for anykind of whitespace is `\s`. `*` means 0 or more:
the string would be `'"ErrorCode":\s*([1-9]|\d{2,})'`

**edit3**: "Code" optional:

Here is the ultimate regex string to match ay kind of `Error` with optional quotation marks, "Code" and the colon:
`"?Error(Code)?"?:?\s*([1-9]|\d{2,})` > `{$_ -match '"?Error(Code)?"?:?\s*([1-9]|\d{2,})'}`
Matchingexamples:

> "ErrorCode": 404
>
> "ErrorCode": 5
>
> "ErrorCode": 0404
>
> "ErrorCode":0404
>
> Error:1
>
> Error1

test it yourself at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com)

Comment: Yes there was a mistake in asking the question I have improved it now.

Comment: @BhaumikBhatt edited the answer to match your question

Comment: I think the errorcode property from my  file is returned as a string because when I use your solution and use echo inside the if statement it does not echo a single line

Comment: the `-match` works just with a string. Is there a whitespace or a tab between `"ErrorCode":` and the value? These are evaluated too!

Comment: Do you have an example string?