# How do I use where condition in powershell

Tags: powershell

Here what I want to do is get the list of the folders that have files which has the value of ErrorCode > 0.

This is what I have done till now.

```
$fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path $scriptPath -Recurse -Include *.data
$FoldersToRename = @() #initialize as array
foreach ($file in $fileNames) {
    If (Get-Content $file | %{$_ -match '"ErrorCode": 0'}) 
{
 echo "matched"   
}
```

Now I have .data file which are being searched by this program. It contains an object with a value of "ErrorCode":value. I want to perform some operations only if that value is greater than zero.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [power shell is giving file not found error when renaming a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58264158/power-shell-is-giving-file-not-found-error-when-renaming-a-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $scriptPath -Filter *.data | 
    ForEach-Object {
        if((Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw) -match '"ErrorCode": [1-9]\d*') {
            "Matched"
        }
}
```

Comment: This works for me after adjusting the regex to account for white space between the errorcode and it's value