# Getting a match even if there is not one

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find the string "ErrorCode":1 using -match in powershell. I found many files with ErrorCode:1. The problem is that when I opened a file given as a result of a match expression to check I did not even find the word ErrorCode and still the filename was given to me as an output

I tried to check files but many file have the string I am searching for but many does not have it.

```
$fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path $scriptPath -Recurse -Include *.data
$FoldersToRename = @() #initialize as array
foreach ($file in $fileNames) {
    If (Get-Content $file | %{$_ -match '"ErrorCode":1'}) 
    # If (Get-Content $file | %{$_ -match '"ErrorCode": [1-9]\d*'}) 
    {
        $FoldersToRename += Split-Path $file
        echo $file
    }
}
```

This is one of the file content I got as an output

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Can someone help explain how this file got to be in output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [power shell is giving file not found error when renaming a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58264158/power-shell-is-giving-file-not-found-error-when-renaming-a-folder)

Comment: How is this duplicate question? Even after using your own code from previous question I am getting some files as output that does not even have a word ErrorCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to seperate the Get-Content command.

```
$fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path $scriptPath -Recurse -Include *.data
$FoldersToRename = @() #initialize as array
foreach ($file in $fileNames) {
    $content = Get-Content $file
    If ($content -match '"ErrorCode":1'}) 
    # If (Get-Content $file | %{$_ -match '"ErrorCode": [1-9]\d*'}) 
    {
        $FoldersToRename += Split-Path $file
        echo $file
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You already have a working solution from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58299592/9529842) to your question.  The problem here is that `Get-Content $file | %{$_ -match '"ErrorCode": [1-9]\d*'}` returns an array (of `true` or `false` values), so the `if` statement is always `true`.

Either go with my previous suggestion, or with [Mike's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58300728/9529842)

Comment: Thank for thee explanation. Now I understand what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you have phrased the IF statement will be true if a file has content. A better way to check the contents of a files using a regex would be to use the Select-String, far simpler than all this looping nonsense. Something like this:

```
$FoldersToRename = (Split-Path (Get-ChildItem -Path $scriptPath -Recurse -Include *.data | Select-String -pattern '"ErrorCode":1').Path) | Select -unique
```

Comment: It gives me error that "Split-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null"

Comment: That's because none of your files contents match that regex. My code was just an example, you may need to add some real world additions for you own context. The point I was making is that Select-String is far more powerful and less code than the way you were going about it.